# How to create dropdowns of my terms to pass to a list to return matching documents in Sharepoint 2016 on Prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store

I have a list of documents that are all tied to terms in the term store.  I'd like to figure out a way to create a 3 drop down lists with the 3 term sets.  The reason I want to do this is so I can pass the parameters from the drop down lists to the list of documents and only return the documents that match the parameters.  What is this called? And do you know of a tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to see documents that are related to a tag or its parent. TThen if I am right, you can do it using content search web part and term deriven Pages. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/how-to-set-up-a-product-centric-website) is some example related to term deriven page and content search. By this way you can collect all the documents/items that related to a term or its children. But if there is only one list you can activate Navigation and Filtering Feature first at site level and then at list level and try to response your need by this simplest way. If I haven't understand the question well please clarify it for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter web part and then connect it to an out of box List View Web Part. The details of how to do that are a bit much to put here, but here is a reference to a Microsoft post that describes it in exhaustive detail:

[Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part on a classic page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f)

Note that as it says in the title, this is only available on classic pages, not modern pages.

Comment: Hi @Joe McShea.  So, I tried adding a Date Filter, and it will send the connection from the date picker to the list of documents.  But, I can't figure out how to get a list of terms to populate at the top to send to the list of documents.

Comment: Sorry Susan, I included the wrong reference. I'll try to find the right one and update my answer, but @Abdollah Kahne's answer is better anyway.  My solution would require developing a custom filter web part as a full trust solution.  His can be done without deploying anything.

Comment: As I was looking for an appropriate reference for creating a custom filter web part, I found that list view web part is not really an option because it won't accept multiple filters. That means that you'd also have to do a custom list view web part, which is probably overkill.